# strange file ownership changes

Tags: windows-7, file-management

There seems to be a process that changes the file ownership on my corporate Windows 7 laptop.

I have the same account name on two different domains, say `GLOBAL\hemal` and `CORP\hemal`. I login to my desktop using `CORP\hemal`, the other account is disabled.

I noticed that several files on my machine are owned by `GLOBAL\hemal`. In general this does cause any issue, I realized this only because `cygwin` complained something about a directory not being safe for creating temp files.

So I changed the file owner to `CORP\hemal`. A little later I got the error again and saw that the owner had changed back to `GLOBAL\hemal`. So I changed the owner on two folders `C:\cygwin` and `C:\eclipse`, which were both owned by the `GLOBAL` to `CORP` and wrote a small script to log their ownership. I confirmed that the onwership keeps getting changed by to `GLOBAL` sooner or later.

So my questions are:

1. Are there any security processes on Windows 7 that would revert the file ownership in this fashion? It seems all files/directories owned by `CORP` get changed to `GLOBAL`
2. Is there a way to identify the process that is making these changed? It doesn't seem like the filesystem watcher can do this, but I am wondering if there is way to make the ownership immutable and thereby get some error message from the offending process.

Comment: What is the full path?  Are we talking the system drive, a user profile directory, remote network drive path?

Comment: All local files and directories. I don't know what you mean by system drive but this happens in files under user directory `c:\user\hemal` as well as to `c:\eclipse` and `c:\cygwin`, it seems all files on my machine owned by `CORP` get their owner modified to `GLOBAL`

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the username on one of the domains as a test?  **A system drive is the drive where the operating system is installed on.**

Comment: No, I cannot change anything in these domains. `C:\` is my system drive.

Answer (score 0):

Using `procmon` from `sysinternals` I found that `c:\Program Files\Quest\vmover` changed the ownership.

Still trying to find out what `vmover` is and why it is changing ownership of files, but `procmon` is a great tool that answered my second question.

I will update this answer when I find out more about `vmover`.